# function overloads when the function is payable

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I'm calling a function from another contract using an interface. The called function is payable and also overloaded.

Example:

```
contract OverloadedContract {
    function foo(uint x) external payable returns(uint) {
        //do something with the value
        return x;
    }

    function foo(int x) external payable returns(int) {
        //do something with the value
        return x;
    }
}

interface IOverloadedContract {
    function foo(uint x) external payable returns(uint);
    function foo(int x) external payable returns(int);
} 

contract CallingContract {
    IOverloadedContract Ioc;
    constructor(address payable _addr) public {
        Ioc = IOverloadedContract(_addr);
    }

    function callIoc(uint x) external payable {
        uint result = Ioc.foo{value:1000}(x);
    }
}
```

The line `uint result = Ioc.foo{value:1000}(x);` will throw the following TypeError:

> TypeError: Member "foo" not unique after argument-dependent lookup in contract IOverloadedContract.uint result = Ioc.foo{value:1000}(x);

This makes sense since,according to the documentation(https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/types.html#function-types), the `{value:1000}` creates a function object before the arguments are specified, meaning the compiler doesn't know which function to choose.

A possible solution would be to use a low-level call i.e.

`(bool sent, bytes result)=_addr.call.value(1000)(abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(keccak256("foo(uint)")),x))`

this would however in my opinion defeat the purpose of function overloading.

I wonder now if there is a workaround/alternative such that one can use overloads while specifying the value? Or should one not use overloads in this case?

Comment: The same error exists in solc 0.5 and the only workaround I know is to make the call in assembly.